# I am trying to write data by rows using for loop, There regularly i need to change data For that i am doing paramerization

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write multiple data in excel by iterating rows, Some times it's working fine , Some times it's not.  I want to iterate upto 12 rows , Every time that grouID will get changes. Some time it's replacing data and some time it's throwing an error as can't get numeric value from text

```
public void writeData(String GroupID) {
   try {
          File src = new File("File.xls");
          Cell cell = null;
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
          HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
          HSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

          for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
             System.out.println("Entering into excel sheet");
             cell = sh1.getRow(i).getCell(22);
             System.out.println("Iterating cells");

             if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                String str = NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                System.out.println("**********Before Replacing**********");
                System.out.println(str);
                cell.setCellValue(GroupID);
             } else {
                       System.out.println("We are not entering  numeric data");
             }
        }
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("File.xls"));
        wb.write(fout);
        fout.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid exception, you need to check the cell type before accessing its value. In your scenario, it seems some times the cell does not contain a numeric value. So,  invoke `getCellType()` on the cell and based on its return type (String or Number) invoke appropriate methods (for String - `getStringCellValue()` and for Number - `getNumericCellValue()`)